# Calling jar from VB6 code java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create

Tags: java, jar, websocket, vb6

In my organisation there is one old application written in VB6. Now my responsibility is to connect this application with 
another java web application using http.

For this I have written one jar which takes input and send it to java web server via port 80 and fetch the result.

When I call this jar file from command line it is working fine and giving me expected result on command prompt

```
java -jar GetWebAppData.jar "input string"
```

But as i need its input in VB6 code I am calling this jar from following VB6 code and expecting that it will give me its output.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor As Long
    bInheritHandle As Long
End Type

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess As Long
    hThread As Long
    dwProcessId As Long
    dwThreadId As Long
End Type

Private Type STARTUPINFO
    cb As Long
    lpReserved As Long
    lpDesktop As Long
    lpTitle As Long
    dwX As Long
    dwY As Long
    dwXSize As Long
    dwYSize As Long
    dwXCountChars As Long
    dwYCountChars As Long
    dwFillAttribute As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    wShowWindow As Integer
    cbReserved2 As Integer
    lpReserved2 As Byte
    hStdInput As Long
    hStdOutput As Long
    hStdError As Long
End Type

Private Const WAIT_INFINITE         As Long = (-1&)
Private Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW  As Long = &H1
Private Const STARTF_USESTDHANDLES  As Long = &H100
Private Const SW_HIDE               As Long = 0&

Private Declare Function CreatePipe Lib "kernel32" (phReadPipe As Long, phWritePipe As Long, lpPipeAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateProcessA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As Long, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, lpProcessAttributes As Any, lpThreadAttributes As Any, ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, lpEnvironment As Any, ByVal lpCurrentDriectory As String, lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long
Private Declare Function ReadFile Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Long, lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long, lpOverlapped As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub GetStartupInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetStartupInfoA" (lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO)
Private Declare Function GetFileSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpFileSizeHigh As Long) As Long

Public Function Redirect(szBinaryPath As String, szCommandLn As String) As String

Print szCommandLn ' added by nilesh

Dim tSA_CreatePipe              As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
Dim tSA_CreateProcessPrc        As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
Dim tSA_CreateProcessThrd       As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
Dim tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo    As PROCESS_INFORMATION
Dim tStartupInfo                As STARTUPINFO
Dim hRead                       As Long
Dim hWrite                      As Long
Dim bRead                       As Long
Dim abytBuff()                  As Byte
Dim lngResult                   As Long
Dim szFullCommand               As String
Dim lngExitCode                 As Long
Dim lngSizeOf                   As Long

tSA_CreatePipe.nLength = Len(tSA_CreatePipe)
tSA_CreatePipe.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0&
tSA_CreatePipe.bInheritHandle = True

tSA_CreateProcessPrc.nLength = Len(tSA_CreateProcessPrc)
tSA_CreateProcessThrd.nLength = Len(tSA_CreateProcessThrd)

If (CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, tSA_CreatePipe, 0&) <> 0&) Then
    tStartupInfo.cb = Len(tStartupInfo)
    GetStartupInfo tStartupInfo

    With tStartupInfo
        .hStdOutput = hWrite
        .hStdError = hWrite
        .dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW Or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
        .wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
    End With

    szFullCommand = """" & szBinaryPath & """" & " " & szCommandLn
    lngResult = CreateProcess(0&, szFullCommand, tSA_CreateProcessPrc, tSA_CreateProcessThrd, True, 0&, 0&, vbNullString, tStartupInfo, tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo)

    If (lngResult <> 0&) Then
        lngResult = WaitForSingleObject(tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hProcess, WAIT_INFINITE)
        lngSizeOf = GetFileSize(hRead, 0&)
        If (lngSizeOf > 0) Then
            ReDim abytBuff(lngSizeOf - 1)
            If ReadFile(hRead, abytBuff(0), UBound(abytBuff) + 1, bRead, ByVal 0&) Then
                Redirect = StrConv(abytBuff, vbUnicode)
            End If
        End If
        Call GetExitCodeProcess(tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hProcess, lngExitCode)
        CloseHandle tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hThread
        CloseHandle tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hProcess

        If (lngExitCode <> 0&) Then Err.Raise vbObject + 1235&, "GetExitCodeProcess", "Non-zero Application exist code"

        CloseHandle hWrite
        CloseHandle hRead
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObject + 1236&, "CreateProcess", "CreateProcess Failed, Code: " & Err.LastDllError
    End If
End If
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim result As String


result = Redirect("ipconfig", "")


Print result

End Sub
```

This script is now calling ipconfig command and printing result . Like this when I call jar from this script it is giving me error:

Calling Jar from above VB6 code just replace `result = Redirect("ipconfig", "")` with `result = Redirect("java", "-jar GetWebAppData.jar 'someinput'")`

Jar is giving exception :

```
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
```

To debug this Jar I have added some sysout in the Jar and those sysout are coming in the VB6 as output but when jar is trying to connect with the socket it is giving exception.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible root cause of

> java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106:
>   create error

might be the missing `SystemRoot` environment variable in the called Java process.

Coud you check this point? `SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS`

I suggest you change the `lpEnvironment` parameter from `vbNullString` to `0&` in `CreateProcess` call. With `vbNullString`, your calling process (Java) doesn't herit the environment variables => no `SystemRoot`.

```
lngResult = CreateProcess(0&, szFullCommand, tSA_CreateProcessPrc, tSA_CreateProcessThrd, True, 0&, 0&, 0&, tStartupInfo, tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo)
```

That my explain your observed behaviour.

Comment: I can see SystemRoot is already set from cmd  it is 
SystemRoot=C:\Windows

Comment: Please check in your created process, not in the cmd where it works!

Comment: While running jar only I set property like java -DSystemRoot=C:\Windows -jar Jarname.jar  .. still it is giving error . Or do I need to set property from VB6 ?

Comment: I checked in VB6 as well using Environ$("SystemRoot") and it is already set to C:\windows

Comment: When I add "nothing" it is giving compiler error "Invalid use of Object" I am new in VB let me know if there is change in method declaration as well :(

Comment: My mistake, replace vbNullString with 0& instead (value of NULL pointer).

Comment: It is giving runtime error after adding 0& on line `Err.Raise vbObject + 1236&, "CreateProcess", "CreateProcess Failed, Code: " & Err.LastDllError`